# Node.js dependency not found even if installed

Tags: node.js, npm, minify

I'm trying to minify a whole folder of css files using minify-all.

But when I run: `minify-all`, I get:

```
Air-di-Giacomo:css jack$ sudo minify-all .
found file: alpha.css
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/node_modules/node-minify/lib/node-minify.js:104
          throw new Error(bin + ' not found !');
          ^

Error: uglifyjs not found !
    at getPath (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/node_modules/node-minify/lib/node-minify.js:104:17)
    at Object.minify.fn.compress (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/node_modules/node-minify/lib/node-minify.js:132:27)
    at Object.minify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/node_modules/node-minify/lib/node-minify.js:83:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/index.js:30:13
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/index.js:14:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at walk (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/index.js:10:36)
    at minifyAll (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/index.js:25:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/index.js:45:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
```

I already tried the following commands:

```
sudo npm install -g uglifyjs
```

and also to reinstall it in the correct order (never know):

```
sudo npm remove -g minify-all
sudo npm remove -g uglifyjs
sudo npm install -g uglifyjs
sudo npm install -g minify-all
```

and finally, in despair, I did:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/
sudo npm install uglifyjs
```

But I still get that error!

This seems to me a node dependency problem, and maybe for some of you it is a stupid problem, do you know how can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try npm rebuild minify-all

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by install it locally.

```
cd /../myCssFolder/
npm init
...
npm install uglifyjs
npm install minify-all
minify-all .
```

of course I prefer to have it globally so I can skip the npm project installation everytime... Any suggestions?

Comment: The idea of npm packages is to add packages to your project `npm install minify-all --save` If you ever need to share the project, all of the packages needed (with the correct version) can be installed by running `npm install` with no issues.

Comment: Ok that's the value of ´--save´. So when I will move the project I will just need to copy the package.json without bring with me the node_modules folder, that will be recreated once I launch ´npm install´. The question was a little bit different but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Global modules always install in `NODE_PATH/bin`。

why not print `echo $path` in terminal， Is there `NODE_PATH/bin` in it ?
if not, you can update ~/.bashrc(if you use bash) or ~/.zshrc(if you use zsh)

```
export PATH="OLD_PATH:NODE_PATH/bin"
```

The `OLD_PATH` is the older one.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a try soon and get back to you.